# Redirecting after upload with Laravel 5.1 and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, file-upload

I'm working with laravel for a few days and i'm trying to make an upload form. When you upload the file the user shouldn't be redirected to any page but it should be displayed on the same page something like: Success. So this is the form:

```
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ URL::to('upload') }}" >
                <label>Upload</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" /><br/>
                <input class="upload_button" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token" />
            </form>
```

This is the controller

```
if(Input::hasFile('file')){
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $user = Auth::id();// !!!!вземи ID на потребителя и му го подай, за да бъде номер на главната му папка!!!!!!!!!!!!
        $file->move('uploads/'.$user, $file->getClientOriginalName());
        echo 'Success';

    }
    else {
        echo 'Please select a file first'; 
    }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".upload_button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'upload',
      data:new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]),
      dataType:"json",
      async:false,
      type:"post",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success:function(response){
        alert(response);
      }
    });
}); });
```

And the route:

```
Route::post('upload', 'UploadController@upload');
```

I just don't want to be redirected to the /upload page. And I don't know how to do that. Could you help

Comment: Maybe your form is submitted when clicking on your `upload_button` (because it is an input of type `submit`) so the form tries to do what is specified in its `action` attribute?

Comment: When I leave the **action** attribute empty it gives me an error
`MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php
    in RouteCollection.php 
    at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php
    at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php 
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php
`

Comment: See DoanTran's answer. The idea is **not** to leave `action` empty (that would make your form just reload the current page, as if you had written `action="./"`), but to prevent the form from performing the normal action. Once you prevent the normal action, then you can leave it empty.

Comment: @ghybs I don't have an idea why but it still redirects me to that url :/

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `form` will redirect you to action's url when you click on the `button` with type = `submit`. But you can prevent this event by add `event.preventDefault()` into your `js` script.

```
$(".upload_button").click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url:'upload',
      data:new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]),
      dataType:"json",
      async:false,
      type:"post",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success:function(response){
        alert(response);
      }
    });
});
```

Done!

Comment: Unfortuantely it still redirects me to: http://localhost/bluedrive/drive/public/upload

Comment: What about attaching the event on the form submit event instead of the submit button click? `jQuery("#upload_form").submit(function…)` with everything else the same? Does it change anything? (make sure to keep the `event.preventDefault();` of course).

Comment: @ghybs `jQuery("#upload_form").submit(function() {            
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url:'upload',
          data:new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]),
          dataType:"json",
          async:false,
          type:"post",
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          success:function(response){
            alert(response);
          }
        });
    }); `

**I've tried it but again it does redirect me**

Comment: Typo or missing `event` argument? `jQuery("#upload_form").submit(function(event)…`

Comment: @ghybs Oh it still redirects me... :/ I think i should give up